# Does git am some_patch apply in an atomic way?

Tags: python, git, gitpython, git-am

I have written an automated code to apply git patches via git python library. However I want to know is there a possibility that some of the
patches are applied and some give error.

```
    try:
        repo.git.execute(["git", "am", "patch")
    except Exception as e:
        for stat in status:
            stat.update({"status": "failure"})
        repo.git.execute(["git", "am", "--abort"])
        return status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to define more precisely what *you* mean by "atomic" here.  In particular, though:

> [What] I want to know is [whether] there [is] a possibility that some of the patches are applied and some give error

It is certainly possible for `git am path` to fail, and the `git am` documentation describes what happens in that case.  If the mailbox-formatted patches contain, say, seven parts, and the first three applied cleanly but the fourth had a merge conflict or other failure, the first three will indeed be applied and the fourth will indeed be not-yet-applied.  If the reason it failed was due to a merge conflict, the index and work-tree will be in the partially-merged state.  If the patch simply did not apply at all, the index and work-tree will match the state produced by applying the third commit.  Either way, `git am` will exit nonzero.  (You may, at this point, use `git am --abort` to put everything back the way it was before you started, with *no* patches applied, or manually fix the problem and then run `git am --continue` to resume the process.)

The [gitpython documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.exc) mentions that `git.exc.GitCommandError` is raised if the underlying Git command exits nonzero.  You would therefore catch an exception here.

Side note: `except Exception` is generally far too broad in Python.  You should typically catch the specific exception(s) you expect here, which in this case might be `git.exc.GitCommandError` (for *`git am` exists and ran, but reported failure*) and `git.exc.GitError` (for *something in general went wrong, such as the Git binary is not installed, or Git claims that this is not a repository at all*, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use Git 2.34 for your atomic process involving `git am --abort`:

When "[`git am --abort`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c84b007c41638814137d296e75446a9b4865fd2/Documentation/git-am.txt#L179)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am#Documentation/git-am.txt---abort))</sup> fails to abort correctly, **it still exited with exit status of 0**, which has been corrected with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021).

See [commit c5ead19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5ead19ea282a288e01d86536349a4ae4a093e4b), [commit 42b5e09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42b5e09d1e555689168941eb639be644d004cb9d), [commit ea7dc01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea7dc012d20feb2b19964c207cd579437d2da26c) (10 Sep 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6c84b00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c84b007c41638814137d296e75446a9b4865fd2), 23 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`am`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5ead19ea282a288e01d86536349a4ae4a093e4b): fix incorrect exit status on am fail to abort
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

So in your python function:

```py
        repo.git.execute(["git", "am", "--abort"])
        return status
```

This would have returned "always true" before Git 2.34, even when the am abort failed.